# TFS - undo merge after get latest

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, merge

I did a search on this issue and found a lot posts and questions but none seems to target my situation.
I had pending changes and i did "Get Latest", i got the conflicts window and wanted to resolve them, so i did a merge as i wanted to keep both my changes and the server's new code. but i forgot to check the block of codes and i just clicked merge (did not  checked in yet!).  i had a conflict on one of the `cproj` files and now i lost some `.cs` files as well.
I think i lost both versions of code and i want to go back and do that merge all over again and do it right, but i don't have a time machine! :)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked temp diff files in  "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp"? when you edit the files in local, the changes will be temporarily saved to the TFS temporary diff files in "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp". The files all have names like "vctmp38604_939733.cs". You can get the previous changes from them.

Answer (score 0):

You basically did an... let's say "Auto Merge". The only help you have is to view the changeset/history of that exact file.
Unless you shelved some changes, there is no way to get both `.cs` files back.

Comment: thank you, how changeset or history will help here as i didn't do a check in yet

Comment: Well you will be able to see past changes you made on your file. Lets say that I made a change on my file, on method `me()`. After a while I delete the method and commit changes. By checking the last changeset that method does not exist, but if you check by commits/changesets/labels you'll find that method. P.S. just go to your file and check history. It will show you whole past of that file!

Comment: yeah but i'm looking for lost code that i never checked in, it existed only on my local repo, hence history won't really show me that.

Comment: @Sag1v I agree, that's why I'm asking you did you shelve it...but I can see you did not...
An advice... when I'm working on a bigger chunk of code, I like to shelve my changes, it's a good practice (I'm saying this for myself, don't know about others :) )
Now the only solution is to write it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't checked in merged changes yet, you still have an option to compare merged files with latest server version and undo all those changes which got merged from server to your local changes manually(especially csproj file in your case). Later, you can be careful to merge again and select all the required blocks.